# Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons React-Native

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-native, textinput

I have a React-Native login component in which I have two `TextInput` components -- email, password -- both have `onChangeText` defined.
When the text changes, I want to update the state of `formData`.

```
...

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  email:"",
  password:"",
})

...
const login = async () => {
  const config = {headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}};
  const body = JSON.stringify(formData); // ---- THIS THROWS ERROR
  try{
    const res = await axios.post("api/login", body, config);

    // Do something with data code...

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

<TextInput onChangeText={text=>setFormData({...formData, email:text})}
<TextInput onChangeText={text=>setFormData({...formData, password:text})}
<TouchableOpacity onPress={login}/>
...
```

**Problem**
Eventually, I do want to send off the form data to an api end point with `application/json` as `Content-Type`. But when I `console.log` out the `formData`, it was not an object with just the `email` and `password` keys... And I couldn't `JSON.stringify` it either because it was some cyclic data or something... I suspect it's the `onTextChange` prop of the `TextInput` that did something to the formData...
Also, when I post make the post request, it'd send multiple `Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons` in the terminal

How can I work this out?

**P.S.**
This is the more complete message of the error

```
Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're %s `%s` on a released/nullified synthetic event. %s. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See https://fb. me/react-event-pooling for more information., accessing the property, type, This is set to null
```

This is the `console.log` of `formData`

```
Class {
[1] [22:05:39]   "_dispatchInstances": FiberNode {
[1] [22:05:39]     "tag": 5,
[1] [22:05:39]     "key": null,
[1] [22:05:39]     "type": "RCTView",
[1] [22:05:39]   },
[1] [22:05:39]   "_dispatchListeners": [Function onResponderRelease],
[1] [22:05:39]   "_targetInst": FiberNode {
[1] [22:05:39]     "tag": 5,
[1] [22:05:39]     "key": null,
[1] [22:05:39]     "type": "RCTView",
[1] [22:05:39]   },
[1] [22:05:39]   "bubbles": undefined,
[1] [22:05:39]   "cancelable": undefined,
[1] [22:05:39]   "currentTarget": 27,
[1] [22:05:39]   "defaultPrevented": undefined,
[1] [22:05:39]   "dispatchConfig": Object {
[1] [22:05:39]     "dependencies": Array [
[1] [22:05:39]       "topTouchCancel",
[1] [22:05:39]       "topTouchEnd",
[1] [22:05:39]     ],
[1] [22:05:39]     "registrationName": "onResponderRelease",
[1] [22:05:39]   },
[1] [22:05:39]   "eventPhase": undefined,
[1] [22:05:39]   "isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
[1] [22:05:39]   "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
[1] [22:05:39]   "isTrusted": undefined,
[1] [22:05:39]   "nativeEvent": Object {
[1] [22:05:39]     "changedTouches": Array [
[1] [22:05:39]       [Circular],
[1] [22:05:39]     ],
[1] [22:05:39]     "identifier": 1,
[1] [22:05:39]     "locationX": 9,
[1] [22:05:39]     "locationY": 4,
[1] [22:05:39]     "pageX": 84.5,
[1] [22:05:39]     "pageY": 589.5,
[1] [22:05:39]     "target": 25,
[1] [22:05:39]     "timestamp": 74210486.447524,
[1] [22:05:39]     "touches": Array [],
[1] [22:05:39]   },
[1] [22:05:39]   "target": 25,
[1] [22:05:39]   "timeStamp": 1600351538612,
[1] [22:05:39]   "touchHistory": Object {
[1] [22:05:39]     "indexOfSingleActiveTouch": 1,
[1] [22:05:39]     "mostRecentTimeStamp": 74210486.447524,
[1] [22:05:39]     "numberActiveTouches": 0,
[1] [22:05:39]     "touchBank": Array [
[1] [22:05:39]       undefined,
[1] [22:05:39]       Object {
[1] [22:05:39]         "currentPageX": 84.5,
[1] [22:05:39]         "currentPageY": 589.5,
[1] [22:05:39]         "currentTimeStamp": 74210486.447524,
[1] [22:05:39]         "previousPageX": 84.5,
[1] [22:05:39]         "previousPageY": 589.5,
[1] [22:05:39]         "previousTimeStamp": 74210358.22676201,
[1] [22:05:39]         "startPageX": 84.5,
[1] [22:05:39]         "startPageY": 589.5,
[1] [22:05:39]         "startTimeStamp": 74210358.22676201,
[1] [22:05:39]         "touchActive": false,
[1] [22:05:39]       },
[1] [22:05:39]     ],
[1] [22:05:39]   },
[1] [22:05:39]   "type": undefined,
[1] [22:05:39] }
```

Comment: Can you post the snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@sapien/handlingtextinput?&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=scj5fbu6g&supportedPlatforms=ios,android,web&name=HandlingTextInput&description=Exampleusage&waitForData=true?)

Comment: Can you see where the `TextInput` component is coming from?

Comment: @PrateekThapa it's built in, this is react-native not reactjs.

Comment: From the error it sounds like you're keeping an event reference. This would make total sense if `onChangeText` were passing the callback the event instead of just the text value like it is supposed to. Try logging the `text` argument in the event handler.

Comment: I know. The code checks out. I was just wondering whether `TextInput` was custom-defined. `onChangeText` returns a the value typed.

Comment: @JaredSmith the text logged out was the character I type in

Comment: As far as I know `onChange` returns the event object not `onChangeText`. Do you mind posting the whole component?

Comment: @EddieLam your code appears to be correct. Can you follow Prateek Thapa's suggestion and make a runnable that shows the issue?

Comment: Sure @JaredSmith Here's the snake link Prateek shared https://snack.expo.io/ZFhHNMYWR

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a work-around:
Instead of sumitting the `formData`, destructure it and than make a new object -- `JSON.stringify` it(the new object) and then submit that in the req body instead.

```
...
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  email: "",
  password: "",
})
const {email, password} = formData;

const login = () => {
  const config = {
    headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
  }
  const body = JSON.stringify({email, password})
  (async()=>{
    const res = await axios.post("/endpoint", body, config)

    ... do something with the res

  })()
}
```